# When saving a model with no new attributes, backbone still sends a PUT to the server

Tags: backbone.js

When listening for a `change` event on a `ProfileView` from the `EditView` to know when it should re-render itself to the users profile again.

If the user just clicks "Update Profile" from the `EditView` but hasn't changed any attributes *(ie. he doesn't want to edit his profile)* a `PUT` is still sent but there is no `change` event so the user is stuck on the edit page until an attribute has been changed..

Why if no attributes have been changed does backbone still send it to the server?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like the logic in your app is flawed. ie. Why would the user click "Update Profile" if he doesn't want to edit his profile? Maybe you need an alternate navigation method in that instance. If you tell Backbone to save a model then it has to send the data to the server to do that as it doesn't know that you don't need it to (you may be recording the save attempt or returning updated values from the server). Maybe look at utilising the changedAttributes method to decide if you need to trigger a save at all.

Comment: Well there is only one button to save and go back to the users profile and it's the "update" button.

Comment: so add a "cancel" button, or don't rely on a change event to return to the user profile page after the update button has been clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Answering to your question, you could check if Model change and only if changed call the save other way call directly the redirect.

First, check this basic example to understand "changedAttributes":

```
var ProfileModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        title : 'hi',
        name : 'there'
    }
}); 
var profile = new ProfileModel();

//Nothing changed so it returns false
console.log( profile.changedAttributes({title: 'hi'}) );

//Title changed so it return a hash with it
console.log( profile.changedAttributes({title: 'hi2'}) );
```

Now figuring your code it must do something like this:

```
var collectedProfile = {
   firstName : this.$('.firstName').val(),
   lastName : this.$('.lastName').val(),
};

if( model.changedAttributes( collectedProfile ) ){
    //instead of listen for the changed listen directly the server response
    model.save(collectedProfile, {success : this.handlerServerResponse })
}else{
    //model did not changed do not needed to call the server
    this.doRedirect();
}


//in your view:
handlerServerResponse : function(){
   //server process completed so let's redirect
   this.doRedirect();
}
```

Comment: @jamcoope any thoughts? doubts?